# catalysts as traces in a monoidal category

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I was fooling around with string diagrams in a monoidal category and I was thinking about them in terms of chemical reactions.  I wondered about bending a wire around and attaching it to the input of the box it came out of.  I realized that what I was looking at was a catalyst.  I then drew a box with many inputs but only one output and saew that this was an autocatalytic reaction.  In this reaction, the product is something necessary for the input. I know that closed loops in the string diagrams are traces.
  Has anyone seen a paper where traces are seen as catalysts?  Has anyone seen work on chemistry using string diagrams in amonoidal category?

Comment: If this exists in the literature, I'm sure John Baez would know about it, cf. e.g. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/rosetta.pdf or try search his blogs.